# How to use main variables on extensions (especially pymongo variables) [discord.py]

Tags: discord.py, pymongo

Premise: I use mongoDB and I don't intend to change databases. So please don't tell me to change database rather avoid this discussion.

I have these variables in my main

```py
dbClient = MongoClient(url)
db = dbClient["DiscordDB"]
memeDB = db["memeList"]
setupBotDB = db["setupBot"]
```

I'm working on this extension

```py
import discord, random, string, asyncio
from discord import app_commands

class addMemeView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, author, title, image, id, interaction, timeout):
        super().__init__(timeout=timeout)
        self.author = author
        self.title = title
        self.image = image
        self.id = id
        self.interaction = interaction 
    
    async def on_timeout(self):
        #...
        await self.interaction.delete_original_response()

    @discord.ui.button(style=discord.ButtonStyle.success, label="✓", custom_id="confirm_button")
    async def first_page_button(self, interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        if interaction.user.id == self.interaction.user.id:
            await interaction.response.defer(ephemeral=True)
            newMeme = {
                "serverID": interaction.guild.id,
                "memeID": self.id,
                "title": self.title,
                "author": self.author,
                "url": self.image.url
            }
            memeDB.insert_one(newMeme)
            #...
            await self.interaction.delete_original_response()
            
    @discord.ui.button(style=discord.ButtonStyle.danger, label="✗", custom_id="cancel_button")
    async def cancel_button(self, interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        if interaction.user.id == self.interaction.user.id:
            #...
            await self.interaction.delete_original_response()

@app_commands.command(name = "addmeme")
async def addmeme(interaction, author: str, title: str, image: discord.Attachment):
    for i in range(0, 10000):
        id = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=8))
        result = memeDB.find_one({"serverID": interaction.guild.id, "memeID": id})
        if (result == None):
            break
        if (i == 10000):
            return
    #...

    await interaction.response.send_message(content="Confermi l'aggiunta di questo meme?", embed=embed, view=addMemeView(author, title, image, id, interaction, 40))

async def setup(bot):
    bot.tree.add_command(addmeme)
```

I saw that it would be useful to use cogs and the idea would work but since I use slash commands I wouldn't know how to add both `memeDB` and `bot.tree.add_command()` and above all I saw that I should call a Pymongo function to create a pool of connections.